# Open excel and position in cell that contains active conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible for excel to open in a cell that contains active conditional formatting? I created a project manager where the current week is highlighted in green through conditional formatting (attachment)... if it is the current week... is it possible via vba or another resource to open excel where the current week is marked?
Regards
[image]

Comment: Yes, it should be doable using the `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: why do you want to search for conditional formatting instead of searching for the value itself?

Comment: because I don't know yet another way. I'm learning and creating this tool at the same time. I have no experience building solutions using microsoft tools. Im an noob

Answer (score 1):

Something like this entered into the Workbook object would give you what you want:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wn As Long
    wn = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now())
    Worksheets("Project Planner").Cells(13, wn + 11).Activate
End Sub
```

Where:

- `wn` is the week number, using Excel's own WeekNum function.
- 13 is the row number to set the cursor to (change if needed)
- 11 is the offset to be added to the `wn` value to locate the column (change if needed)